# ASP.NET MVC NullReferenceException when inheriting from a Base Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I've got a base controller that I inherit all of my Controllers from.  It's job is to basically set caching and error handling as well as check for mobile browsers.

**My UI works fine, but my Unit Tests are failing.**

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

<HandleError()> _
<CompressFilter()> _
<OutputCache(Duration:=30, VaryByParam:="id")> _
Public Class BaseController : Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Protected Overrides Function View(ByVal viewName As String, ByVal masterName As String, ByVal model As Object) As System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult
        Dim ismobile As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice

        If ismobile Then
            Return MyBase.View(viewName, "Mobile", model)
        Else
            Return MyBase.View(viewName, "Site", model)
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

The error I'm getting in my Unit test is on `Dim ismobile As Nullable(Of Boolean) = Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` saying

> Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object.

#### Edit:

Here is what my test class looks like

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports UrbanNow.Core
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> Public Class EventsControllerTest

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub Index()
        ''# Arrange
        Dim controller As EventsController = New EventsController()

        ''# Act
        Dim result As ViewResult = CType(controller.Index(), ViewResult)

        ''# Assert
        Dim viewData As ViewDataDictionary = result.ViewData
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's pretty much just a rip off of the test that gets setup when you create a new MVC Web Application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @JohnSaunders heh, trolling for votes on a 4 yr old post. In fact... I asked this first, so not necessarily a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Request.Browser` is an extension property, it is the one of the logical places for an exception to be thrown. Alternatively, implementation of `IsMobileDevice` tries to access something that is null when run out of a unit testing environment.

**Edit** After looking at the test code, it seems the problem is that `Request` property on the controller is never set. When the page is executed by ASP .NET, the framework populates it with the valid object. When unit testing, you need to provide a mock for `Request` that does enough to make the test not crash.

There are two ways to do it:

1. Create a class that derives from `RequestBase` and implement enough of it to make `Browser`
   not crash.
2. Use a mocking framework (like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)) to create a mock at runtime. You would still need to implement whatever functionality that make `Browser.IsMobile` actually work.

My suggestion would be to use Moq to mock `Request` to return another Moq mock that mocks `Browser` property. Then you can simply return true/false for `IsMobileDevice`, so that you can isolate the controller functionality without worrying about how `Browser.IsMobileDevice` works.

C# example code:

```
Mock<RequestBase> requestMock = new Mock<RequestBase>();
Mock<Browser> browserMock = new Mock<Browser>();
requestMock.Setup(request=>request.Browser).Returns(browserMock.Object);
browserMock.Setup(browser=>browser.IsMobileDevice).Returns(true);
controller.Request = requestMock.Object;
```

Comment: The error is thrown on Request.Browser.  I'm not sure how to account for that in my unit testing.

Comment: Yep, that's because `BaseController.Request` is never set and is always null. See edit.

Comment: in the second line i guess you are trying to declare browserMock?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mock the request properly?

Comment: Possibly not.  I've NEVER done unit testing before.  I'll update my question with my test class

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this.

1. Mock the HTTPRequest instance as Igor mentioned.
2. **Set the required  private set properties using reflection. This is extremely useful to inject some dependency directly into the subject that is being tested.** (Mocking frameworks internally does this though) . This approach helps when you are not familiar with Mocking Frameworks.

E.g.,

```
  private static void SetPrivateSetPropertyValue(Type type, object obj, string fieldName, object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(fieldName);
        propInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
```

Consuming Code

E.g.,

```
this.SetPrivateSetPropertyValue(Request.GetType(),reqInstance,"Browser",browInstance);
```

Hope this helps,

Thanks,
Vijay